# How to determine if a 'malloc' symbol came from the source or from the compiler?

Tags: c++, winapi, portable-executable

Using Dll injection I was able to hook the `malloc` symbol from `msvcrt.dll`, and to print a log of all the calls to `malloc` from the injected process. The problem is that in the log I can found calls to `malloc` that are not  in the target exe, see further example.

I believe there is a way to solve this, based on the returned addresses of the `malloc` calls that I found in the hooking process. Here is the log file for a target PE, compiled with tcc:

```
0 malloc(18)    memory allocated at: 10229112    the return adress is 74ab770a.
1 malloc(4096)  memory allocated at: 10232824    the return adress is 74ab770a.
2 malloc(15)    memory allocated at: 10229144    the return adress is 401022.
3 malloc(15)    memory allocated at: 10229168    the return adress is 401041.
4 malloc(15)    memory allocated at: 10229192    the return adress is 401060.
```

In the exe file, only the last three calls exists, and it's clear that the other came from a whole different PE.

How I can detect which calls from the `exe` file and which from different PE when printing the log?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Smells like XY problem.

Comment: Also, why mention macro's? I suppose C++ macro's could expand to `malloc`, but the mention of macro's in combination with `.text` suggests a level of confusion that's not addressable with a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I suggested macros as a solution, don't know if it's the right approach

Comment: *hook the malloc symbols* - which concrete function you hook ? in which *PE* this `malloc` located ? i can guess that you hook it inside some dll. say inside *msvcrt.dll*. then how you hook ? exist different ways. i can guess that by patching (detor) code of `msvcrt.malloc`. as result you catch calls when it internally call from *msvcrt.dll* and from another modules, include *exe* too

Comment: in any case by return address easy can view from which *pe* was call. and your question unclear : what you mean under "from the compiler" ? what mean "from source" ?

Comment: @RbMm yeah it hooked from `msvcrt.dll`. I like your approach, but I can't see how its "easy can view from which pe was call`, this is actually my question...

Comment: your question in current edition unclear. the view is very easy. what concrete you need view ?

Comment: some mechanism to determine if the call is explicit in the source, or that it came from somewhere else, like the compiler.

Comment: i can not understand what you say. *call is explicit in the source, or that it came from somewhere else, like the compiler.* - absolute unclear for me

Comment: Ok. As I mentioned in the post, there are three calls to malloc that are explicit in the source. like `int* a = (int*)malloc(15); int* b = (int*)malloc(15); int* c = (int*)malloc(15)` Those are the explicit calls in the source. and you can see in the input they came from the same PE. beside those there are two more calls to `malloc` that the compiler added. I need somehow to print in the log only the calls that came from the source. Hope its more clear now... (and thanks a lot for trying to help)

Comment: *that the compiler added* - who say this for you ? this is ofcourse wrong. this calls from another dll. compiler is nothing added. still your question and problem absolute unclear.

Comment: what is **source** ? unclear. compiler is nothing add. compiler can not generate yourself call to unknown external function. and from your log clear visible that first 2 calls was from another dll. not from *exe*. you need more exactly ask another question - what concrete information you need got from return address

Comment: Cool that mean I had a wrong assumption, thanks for detecting it. So, we both can see that the three `malloc(15)` return address is to a different module\PE\Dll whatsoever. How can I print only the calls that came from the .exe? like the three `malloc(15)`?

Comment: *and it's clear that they come from a whole different section.* - and it's clear that they come from a whole different **PE**.

Comment: *How can I print only the calls that came from the .exe* - this is very easy. i can answer if you ask exactly this question

Comment: Here, I just edit the question for you :)

Comment: Well, how can I print only the calls that came from the .exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we hook function from dll, say `msvcrt!malloc` calls can be from different *PE* modules. we can take base address of calling module from returnAddress call [`GetModuleHandleExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexw) with `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` flag. if we need detect are call was from *exe* we can compare this address with base address of *exe* which we can get via [`GetModuleHandleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew)

code can look like

```
HMODULE hmod;
if (GetModuleHandleEx(
    GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS|
    GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, (PCWSTR)_ReturnAddress(), &hmod))
{
    static HMODULE hmodEXE = 0;

    if (!hmodEXE)
    {
        hmodEXE = GetModuleHandleW(0);
    }

    DbgPrint("%p: call %sfrom exe\n", _ReturnAddress(), hmodEXE == hmod ? "" : "not ");
}
else
{
    DbgPrint("%p: call not from any PE\n", _ReturnAddress());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your'e a good teacher, showing me my mistakes and than solving the problem. Now I can understand what you did, and not only paste it in my code :)

Comment: @ZENir - the calls of course was not from compiler. in your log clear visible that this was from another dll. if want, by have dll `hmod` we can get dll name/path - so say from wich concrete dll was call. for example you can call `GetModuleFileName` for `hmod` returned from `GetModuleHandleEx`